# how to get certificate chain (root and intermediates) from an XMLSignature

Tags: java, security, xml-signature

Hi I just have contructed an org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature from a xml that complies with xmldsig w3c recommendation, and I can see that the xml contains all certificate chain in

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
```

elements, but using the XMLSignature API I can see that I can only access the user certificate and the issuer one, but not the complete chain, is there an straightforward way to get this done through xmlsec API?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, not the most clean, but it works:

```
XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement,
                null);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = signature.getKeyInfo();
        NodeList x509Certificates = keyInfo.getElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "X509Certificate");

        ArrayList<X509Certificate> allCertificates = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x509Certificates.getLength(); i++) {
            Node x509CertificateElement = x509Certificates.item(i);
            byte[] decodedX509Certificate = Base64.decode(x509CertificateElement.getTextContent());
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedX509Certificate));
            allCertificates.add(x509Certificate);
        }

        // now you have all certificates in allCertificates
```